# history API in HTML 5

Tags: html, html5-history

I am using Google chrome and i have tested, using one of the detection techniques mentioned in Dive into HMTL 5, for support for the History API. But the following piece of code does not seem to work. Can anybody let me know what am i missing out ?

```
function demo()
 {
  alert("history changing");
if(window.history && history.pushState)
{
    alert("api supported");
}
else
    alert("api not supported");
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    history.pushState(null,null,"\try.html");
}
}
```

The for loop, wherein i expect the url "try.html" to be inserted 20 times in the history of the browser, does not seem to work. I called this function from a page, named "try.html", wherein the function "demo" is executed on page load. The page, "try.html", simply has a line of normal text. What i want to do is that when the user, after loading the page, "try.html", clicks on the back button of the browser he'll still remain on the same page, since the history should be containing 20 entries of the same page, i.e. "try.html" but it does not. Why?

Comment: Wanna enlighten us on exactly what part of that code doesn't work? Instead of saying "it doesn't work", try telling us what the output is and what the expected output is. Thanks.

Comment: oh i am sorry. so it goes this way. The for loop, wherein i expect the url "try.html" to be inserted 20 times in the history of the browser,  does not seem to work. I called this function from a page, named "try.html", wherein the function "demo" is executed on page load. The page, "try.html", simply has a line of normal text. What i want to do is that when the user, after loading the page, "try.html", clicks on the back button of the browser he'll still remain on the same page, since the history should be containing 20 entries of the same page, i.e. "try.html".

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that your stateObj is null.

Comment: but is it necessary to have the stateObj ?

Comment: I don't know. The [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) didn't really address the issue of null values. Perhaps you should try with some dummy data just to rule that out.

Comment: i did try it and a couple of other things but it still does not seem to work. Can you suggest something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.  There are two problems you could be having:

1. If you try and run your function from a `file://` URI then you'll get a security error.  Chrome is silent about this but Firefox reports the error.  You need to put the page on a web server and access it over `http://`.
2. The string `"\try.html"` means a tab character followed by `ry.html`, you probably mean `"/try.html"`.

[Here is a working example](http://www.boogdesign.com/try-2.html) based on your code.

Comment: hi! thank you for the reply. I tried out both the things. Changed "\try.html" to "\1.html" and uploaded the file onto a web server as well. but the problem still does not get solved. i still can not see the updated added entries in the browser history. can you please help.

Comment: For your reference:- [link] (http://www.sonatechsolutions.com/abhinav)
is the folder that contains the 2 html files named index.html and 1.html. The file index.html contains the above script and so should update the browser history with 20 1.html links. But it does not. Please let me know what am i missing ...

Comment: @geek_ji stop using `\ ` instead of `/` in your URI paths.  `\ ` is a JS escape character.

Comment: @robertc....thank you .. really thanks to you a lot. And this might just sound a little weird but the dumbest person i have seen ever on this planet is ME. The history of the browser was actually getting updated but i just was not able to see the same update in the history tab of google chrome. What i mean is that after the script executes internally the browser does maintain a 20 entries of the pg. 1.html on the stack, but this is can not be seen visually in the history tab of google chrome.